# Webapp2 get_user_by_password raises TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: python, webapp2

I'm new to webapp2. I've tried to make a custom user model compilant with authentication system.
But every time my program calls get_user_by_password it raises an TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects.
I've tried even to run somebody elses applications with custom models and it won't work neither.
For example I get the same error with this project https://gist.github.com/jgeewax/2942374.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in   default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "D:\STUDIA\Semestr 10\Praca Magisterska\Projekty\test\main.py", line 83, in dispatch
response = super(BaseHandler, self).dispatch()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\STUDIA\Semestr 10\Praca Magisterska\Projekty\test\main.py", line 141, in post
self.auth.get_user_by_password(username, password)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2_extras\auth.py", line 459, in get_user_by_password
silent=silent)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2_extras\auth.py", line 278, in validate_password
return self.get_user_by_auth_password(auth_id, password, silent=silent)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2_extras\auth.py", line 151, in get_user_by_auth_password
return self.user_to_dict(user)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2_extras\auth.py", line 207, in user_to_dict
user_dict = dict((a, getattr(user, a)) for a in self.user_attributes)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2_extras\auth.py", line 207, in <genexpr>
user_dict = dict((a, getattr(user, a)) for a in self.user_attributes)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 604, in __get__
return getattr(model_instance, self._attr_name())
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 752, in _attr_name
return '_' + self.name
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Comment: more than likely a call to `dict.get` that is returning None, what should self.name be?

Answer (score 7):

The error explains that you cannot perform string concatenation of a string (`'_'`) and an object which value is `None`. It means at this point `self.name` is `None`, so you need to trace where `self.name` is being defined, and if you are storing the value correctly

If you still want to concatenate the two values, consider using string formatting instead of the '+' sign.

eg `return '_%s' % self.name` would return `'_None'` if `self.name` value is `None`